# ascending order foreach

Tags: c#

I am trying to check for ascending order in this array
But not sure how to use a foreach

```
 foreach (double d in dSize)
        {

            if (dSize.ToString() != null)
            {
                double dSize1;
                string str1 = dSize.ToString();

                bool success1 = double.TryParse(str1, out dSize1);
                if ( dSize < 0.0)
                {
                    errMsg1 = " data grid should contain number >= 0";
                }
                //else
                //{
                //    errMsg1 = " data grid must be entered";
                //}
            }


                *if (inputs.dSize[rowCount] <= inputs.dSize[rowCount - 1])
                {
                    errMsg = "value in row " + (rowCount + 1) + " should be greater than the value in row " + rowCount;
                }
            }*
            swRpt.WriteLine(errMsg);
        }
```

I've done the second part using a for loop. Would like to change it to a foreach

Comment: Where's the `for` loop? (You say the 2nd part is using a for loop)

Comment: Is that if commented out?  What are the asterisks?

Comment: What's wrong with using a for loop? If it's working for you, why change it?

Comment: So. presumably, dSize is a collection of some kind (since it's what you are looping over), so why do you have dSize.ToString()? And why are you then trying to parse it as an int?

Comment: Also, can you clarify your question. Some people are confused as to whether you are trying to iterate through the collection from the end to the beginning or if you are (as I think) just trying to check that the values are in ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remember the previous value from one iteration to the next. The issue with using foreach for this (as opposed to the raw iterator) is that you need a special case for the first value:

```
Double lastDouble = null;
foreach(double d in dSize) {
    if ((lastDouble != null) && (lastDouble > d)) {
        errMsg = "value out of sequence";
        break;
    }
    lastDouble = d;
}
```

but then you've lost the row number for the error. You could also prime your last value from the first entry and skip one using LINQ

```
double lastDouble = dSize.First();
foreach(double d in dSize.Skip(1)) {
    if (lastDouble > d) {
        errMsg = "value out of sequence";
        break;
    }
    lastDouble = d;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not...

```
  for(int i = dSize.Length-1; i>=0;i--)
  {
      double d = dSize[i];
      ...
      ...
      ...
  }
```